# What layer of skin and approximate depth would this be?

Tags: dermatology, hypodermic, capillary-capillaries

So this for a school thing and I am completely stuck on working out what it is. I'm thinking reticular dermis but thats just a guess.

"It is a clean wound positioned just below the elbow crease that bleeds slowly but consistently for about 10 minutes, when the blood is washed away white can be seen inside, is about a 1.2mm in width and 1cm in length. It takes about 3 weeks to heal (wounds similar to cat scratches usually heal in 5 days on this subject) and leaves a purple scar to begin with. What layer and sublayer of skin is this likely to be in, what depth range too?"

I figure that the white must be collagen and the fact that it bleeds slowly but consistently would suggest it was through the surface capillaries and long healing time a decent depth. This is what makes me think reticular dermis but I am really not sure. What do you guys think, it would be great if you could approximate the depth too?

Thanks